# Make SE domains more password manager friendly

Tags: feature-request, safari, password

## Edit

The password is not used anywhere else:

[image: screenshot]

## Original

Safari doesn't recognize some Stack Exchange sites as part of the main site, and therefore warns that the same password is "reused".

[image: screenshot]

## Request

#### Help Safari realize it's all the same site, by making all domains `name.se`

Note: Safari cannot tell you something like "no passwords are being reused besides for SE sites", so I don't know if I have reused passwords for anything else, either.

Comment: What does Safari consider a "site" to be?  Just the base domain (`stackexchange.com`)?  It's very unclear to me, and it seems this is more likely a problem with Safari password manager than this site (the PM needs to work with the site, not the other way around).

Comment: Every site uses the exact same credentials, and it's not possible to have one password for Stack Overflow and a different password for Server Fault. They are the same account and use the same password. You're not reusing the same password, because there is only one password that exists.

Comment: Right. Because stackoverflow.com is a different domain than stackexchange.com and unless the password manager is aware that they are the same network with the same credentials, it won't know the password changed. You need to update them both.

Comment: There's nothing we could possibly do to help the password manager with that, and I don't know if any password managers actually care about those edge cases. It's simply a thing that falls into the realm of your responsibility.

Comment: SO/SE really have failed me. No. This is not my responsibility. It’s yours. You should use subdomains - or whatever other system - to create a unique SE login. And the least customer-centric company on the planet award goes to…

Answer (score 2):

It turns out Safari *is* already smart enough to detect that these websites are the same:

[image]

See? No warning signs in the last column (and yes, I'm sure the passwords are all the same). The message in the footer is just a legend for the last column, not a message that the selected sites are reusing passwords in a non-safe way. You either must be using the same password for *another* website (which one will be hard to find) or something went wrong during sign up.

Either way, if you don't use the search filter but simply click the header of the last column, you can find the other sites for which you are reusing passwords. If you can't fix your Stack Exchange setup, but only those three sites are left, you can consider it done.

Comment: Creating new passwords using safari doesn’t work. Because they don’t get updated everywhere. See previous edit. Also: safari does recognize that “chess.se” and “music.se” are the same. But it complains about SO and Stack apps - which are completely separate links. See screenshot. I cannot ignore these warnings as some sites don’t support such long passwords as Safari ones.

Comment: Crap, I'm reading the message wrong. I'll be back with an update.

Comment: no worries. Have a great weekend!

Comment: I updated my answer. For me, Safari understands it's the same group of websites. Have a nice weekend too!

Comment: I’ll check in this, thanks

Comment: I can confirm that the password I have saved for SO, SE, and SA, is not used anywhere else. I still get those warnings, so I don't think Safari understand they are the same website.

Comment: Which version of Safari are you running? I have Version 13.0 (15608.2.2)

Comment: Version 12.1.2 (14607.3.9). You might try changing your SO/SE/SA password and see what happens.

Comment: I tried. Issue remains: https://imgur.com/a/hLGVEUD

Comment: I reported this to Apple, let's see what happens.

Comment: Unless it’s a subdomain there is no way a password manager will recognize them as being one.